# how to configure my app to Apple business manager account

Tags: ios, swift

[image]

I have an apple Business manager account, but I am not able to configure my app to distribute it to all the people.

Comment: Can you clarify your question - Do you want to make an app available as a B2B app, available to your Apple Business Manager account?

Comment: Yes @sneacsu an app as B2B, I have a Business Manager account in apple.

Comment: In App Store Connect you make the app available to your Apple Business Manager organisation identifier.

Comment: No my app not available to App Store Connect enrolled  Apple Developer Program, it is a new one to configure the Business Manager account, How can I do that?

Comment: If you want to make an app you have created available under Apple Business Manager, you need to submit it via App Store Connect just like a normal App Store app. In "Pricing and availability" in App Store Connect you make it available to your Apple Business Manager organisation.

Comment: Thanks, @Paulw11 How to make it available to Apple Business Manager My organization, I Login App Store Connect to my  Apple Business Manager Account but it's not login.

Comment: You need a paid developer membership, either individual or organisational, then you will have access to App Store connect.

Comment: Yes, I already paid for Apple Business Manager Account for Business, then is it possible to access?

Comment: Apple Business Manager is free and is different to the Developer program. Having joined the developer program and paid the fee there are a number of legal agreements you need to complete.  Once all of that is done and you have access to App Store Connect you can upload app builds, submit them for review and make them available to Apple Business Manager

Comment: Thanks, @Paulw11 I have both paid developer program and Apple Business Manager Account both have different login ids So How can I access my app to Apple Business Manager Account?

Comment: Log in to App Store Connect with the developer Apple ID. Go to the app. Go to pricing and availability. Add your Apple Business Manager organisation id there to make the app available

Comment: Where can I add  Apple Business Manager organization id from pricing and availability?

Comment: Under "Distribution for business and education" you select "available for private distribution to specific organisations on Apple Business Manager"

Comment: But Distribution for Business and Education in pricing and availability radio button only there, when selecting "Available for private distribution to specific organizations on Apple Business Manager" its disable to click now and How can I configure Apple Business Manager there?

Comment: Have you ever made this app available generally via the App Store? Has your admin user completed and accepted the latest paid app distribution agreement?

Comment: After Completion of the paid app distribution agreement, How can I distribute that app to my organization in the business manager account?

Comment: Log in to App Store Connect with the developer Apple ID. Go to the app. Go to pricing and availability. Add your Apple Business Manager organisation id there to make the app available

Comment: Thanks, @Paulw11 but after adding organization id how to publish my app, Is this possible without adding devices to publish my organization?

Comment: Yes.  Just upload a build and submit it for review.  Once it is approved you can download it using your MDM or generate redemption codes in Apple Business Manager.

Comment: Thanks, @Paulw11 can you explain the difference between MDM and redemption codes? Where can I get redemption codes? and a public key of MDM?

Comment: Using an MDM is easier; you can just distribute the app to your devices using policy. With redemption codes you need to somehow get a code to each user and have them redeem it using the App Store.

Comment: Thanks, @Paulw11 where can I get MDM public key? and explain how to use it?

Comment: You would typically just use a commercial MDM such as Meraki or Workspace One or Mobile Iron it JAMF or...  building your own MDM is quite an undertaking.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204393/discussion-between-senthil-and-paulw11).